# Remove Duplicate in string list Type Error python

Tags: python, maya

if I then try to remove the duplicates I get a TypeError...Why?

tempList=list(set(tempList))

## Error: TypeError: file  line 29: 'str' object is not callable #

This is the real code:

```
# Lists all UI elements
allUI=pm.lsUI()[24:28]

#Main Window Name
win='searchElementsUI'
#Lists for UI Hierachy
allSplitUI=[]
maxLenUI=[]
parentDict={}

#Splits UI Elements
for ui in allUI:
    allSplitUI.append(ui.split('|'))

#Max length of UISplit
for ui in allSplitUI:
    maxLenUI.append(len(ui))
maxLenUI=max(maxLenUI)

#Adds main Parents to list
tempList=[]
for i in range(maxLenUI):
    tempList=[]
    for ui in allSplitUI:
        try:
            tempList.append(ui[i])

        except:pass
    tempList=list(set(tempList))
    parentDict['list%s'%i]=tempList
```

Here the complete traceback from maya:

```
# Lists all UI elements
allUI=pm.lsUI()

#Main Window Name
win='searchElementsUI'
#Lists for UI Hierachy
allSplitUI=[]
maxLenUI=[]
parentDict={}

#Splits UI Elements
for ui in allUI:
    allSplitUI.append(ui.split('|'))

#Max length of UISplit
for ui in allSplitUI:
    maxLenUI.append(len(ui))
maxLenUI=max(maxLenUI)

#Adds main Parents to list
tempList=[]
for i in range(maxLenUI):
    tempList=[]
    for ui in allSplitUI:
        try:
            tempList.append(ui[i])

        except:pass
    tempList=list(set(tempList))
    parentDict['list%s'%i]=tempList
# Error: 'str' object is not callable
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 29, in <module>
# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable #
```

Comment: This is not your real code. You would not get that error from that code.

Comment: I ve added the real code. Maybe you can help

Comment: Add the entire, real stacktrace. Also, this is still not your real code, because the 29th line would not have that error.

Comment: It is the complete code. I dont understand why I get this error...

Comment: POST THE COMPLETE STACK TRACE

Comment: Edited the post. This is the whole stack trace within maya. OR tell me how to show you the COMPLETE stack trace.

Comment: There is no way this is your real code, because line 29 only has calls to `list` and `set`, and your code does not assign a string to either variable.

Comment: As I said from the beginning. It is the whole code. 
Thats why I dont understand the error. 
Even in a fresh maya with the 30 lines of code I get the error.

Comment: What I strongly suggest is: (1) you split this up into functions, so you can at least have an indication of the function (2) use a list comprehension to perform the last loop.

Comment: Assuming this is your real code, I suggest you replace substantially all of it with the code I provide in my answer. If you need the dict thing, then clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you have either not posted your real code, or something very odd is going on.

However, you can replace pretty much your whole script with the below line:

```
import itertools
alluis = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ui.split('|') for ui in pm.lsUI()))
```

This splits, flattens, and uses `set` to uniquify.

Comment: Thanks Marcin,

I am really new to scripting so any help is much appreciated. 
What I am actually tryíng to do is to create a simple hierachy layout using cmds.treeView
It should create a hierachy of all ui elements in maya.
With that I can then add buttons or customs controls to any part in mayas ui.
Maybe you have a simpler approach to that.

The itertools, helps a lot already! Thanks

Comment: @arvidurs I'm not familiar with maya. I assume you are using the 3d rendering programme, and not some other maya.

Comment: yeah the 3D software.

Comment: @arvidurs I suggest you accept this answer, then, and ask subsequent questions when you next hit a snag.

Comment: many of the UI elements are temporary and most of them have auto-generated names - you'll have a tough time sorting out which items are actually around when the time comes to use the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
#Convert to a set
a =set(tempList)

seen = set()
result = []
for item in a:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        result.append(item)
```